# Ajax call freeze while process request from callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a common ajax call function for my application for optimizing code. the problem is while I call the function its freeze page. Please check below JS:

```
$(fuction(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        var data = getData('myaction/getinfo', []);
    })
});

function getData(url, data) {
    var result = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: data,
        error: function () {
            console.log('error');
            $('.custom-loader').fadeOut("slow");
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.custom-loader').fadeIn("slow");
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('.custom-loader').fadeOut("slow");
        },
        success: function (res, status) {
            result = res;
            $('.custom-loader').fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

While I click a button, ajax request working pretty well but loader not showing until ajax return response (unable to click until response return).

If I on async with `async: true` this will continue execution code which breaks functionality (Next execution depend on ajax response). Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks an advance!

Comment: Check how the request is going in the Network tab of the devtools. It should show you the timing of the request

Comment: `async: false` will stop the code execution and as of that freez the window, until the request is completed, that's how it is specified. So there is no way around using `async: true` and rewriting your code so that it will work with async functions.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @YaakovAinspan and @t.niese! got the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to asynchronous operations is callbacks (unless you use es6 `async`/`await`). This means that instead of expecting functions to return values you pass them callbacks, which are functions that take as a parameter the return value.

In your case this would look like,

```
$(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        getData('myaction/getinfo', [], function(res){
            console.log(res);
        });
    })
});

function getData(url, data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        error: function () {
            console.log('error');
            $('.custom-loader').fadeOut("slow");
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.custom-loader').fadeIn("slow");
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('.custom-loader').fadeOut("slow");
        },
        success: function (res, status) {
            $('.custom-loader').fadeOut("slow");
            callback(res);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, It's working cool!

Answer (score 1):

You should get use to the "callback" mechanisim in Javascripts. Just call your post processing method in the "success" event handler.

```
$(fuction(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        getData('myaction/getinfo', []);
    })
});

function postProcessing(data){
    //Put your processing logic here. e.g. Populate the data on the screen control
}

function getData(url, data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        error: function () {
            console.log('error');
            $('.custom-loader').fadeOut("slow");
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.custom-loader').fadeIn("slow");
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('.custom-loader').fadeOut("slow");
        },
        success: function (res, status) {
            $('.custom-loader').fadeOut("slow");
            postProcessing(res);
        }
    });
}
```